# Copy Folders to Another Folder Based on List of Known Folder Names in OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, zsh

I need to find folders within a directory that match a known list and copy them to a subfolder.

So far I have found solutions for moving files via a list, but I can't figure out how to do that with folder names. I can move folders individually with cp -R, but don't understand how to use a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
% mkdir subfolder {a..z}  # create dirs for our test case

% ls  # list them all
a/  b/          c/  d/  e/  f/  g/  h/  i/  j/  k/  l/  m/  n/  o/  p/  q/  r/
s/  subfolder/  t/  u/  v/  w/  x/  y/  z/

% list=(f o b a r)  # make a list

% mv $list[@] subfolder/  # move all files in the list to subfolder

% ls subfolder  # list the contents of subfolder
a/  b/  f/  o/  r/

%
```

(`%`  is our prompt. You shouldn't type that.)

To read a list from a text file:

```bsh
% list=( ${(f)"$( < file )"} )  # if each name is on a separate line

% list=( ${(s:,:)"$( < file )"} )  # if they're separated by commas

%
```

Comment: Thanks Marlon, I appreciate it. This is for Windows only, correct? What is the purpose of a/ b/ c/ etc?

Can you comment on what is happening with the commands? My guess is that a/ b/ is what I would type in from my list of folder names. So if I want to copy Folder32 I would have Folder32/ and in % list=(Folder32 b c) ? Ideally I would be able to reference a text file with a list of folder names instead of typing each one into the command line. Sorry, I am really lost here.

I should note that I am looking for a solution on mac os using terminal. But, I could use Windows too.

Comment: "This is for Windows only, correct?" No, I did this on macOS.

Comment: `% ` is the prompt. You don't type that.

Comment: Every line that is not prefixed by `% ` is command output.

Comment: "What is the purpose of a/ b/ c/ etc?" That's the output of the `ls` command. Those are the directories we made with `mkdir`.

Comment: Maybe you should first read a basic tutorial?

Comment: Thanks a ton, and sorry for the beginner questions.

Comment: "mkdir subfolder {a..z}"  creates a folder for everything a - z, and also creates a subfolder. This is to set up a test to try the command I guess.

"%list=(a b c)" defines the list of folders to call from

"mv $list subfolder" calls upon the defined list and puts it in the subfolder.

So in all, when I'm already in a directory with a list I just do this:

list=(a b c)
mv $list subfolder

WOW! Thank you, very easy. I sadly spent hours looking into this, so I really felt like I needed some help.

How would I reference a text or csv file for my list?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I added comments now to make it more clear.

Comment: @Drew I also added some basic examples on how to read values from files. If you actually want to read from a CSV file, though, I recommend not using a shell script, as that can get quite complicated. Python has good CSV support, though: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Marlon! This solved my problem. The extra comments are appreciated. :)

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your list of directories is in a text file `dirs.txt` (one directory name per line), and you want to move them to the folder `subdir`. You can issue the `bash` command:

`` $ for f in `cat dirs.txt` ; do mv $f subdir; done ``

Comment: @MarlonRichert perhaps you did not notice that the question is also tagged `bash`

Comment: You’re right. Sorry.